# Elasticsearch aggrecation give me 2 results insted of one result

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to aggregate on the brand field and is give me two results instead of one

The brands_aggs give me from this text

### {name : "Brand 1"}

2 results

`Brand` and `1`

But Why I need only `Brand 1`

is separate the word brand and 1 from (Brand 1)

and is give me 2 results in the aggrecation

### my mappings where I want to aggregate

```
 mapping = {  
        "mappings": {

            "product": {
                "properties": {

                    "categories": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "fielddata": True
                    }

                    "brand": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "fielddata": True
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## my post request

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": { "categories": "AV8KW5Wi31qHZdVeXG4G" }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "brand_aggs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand" }
        },
        "categories_aggs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "categories" }
        }
    }

}
```

## response from the server

```
{
    "took": 18,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {

        "categories_aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "av8kw5wi31qhzdvexg4g",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "av8kw61c31qhzdvexg4h",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "av8kxtch31qhzdvexg4a",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        },

        "brand_aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "1",  <==== I dont need this , why is give me that ??
                    "doc_count": 1    
                },
                {
                    "key": "brand",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        },

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping has property fields which is used when you want to have multiple analyzers for the same field. In your case valid name of your field is 'brand.keyword'. When you call your aggregate for just 'brand' it use default mapping defined for string.

So your query should be:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": { "categories": "AV8KW5Wi31qHZdVeXG4G" }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "brand_aggs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand.keyword" }
        },
        "categories_aggs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "categories.keyword" }
        }
    }

}
```

Property field is useful when you want for example search the same property which multiple analyzers, for example:

```
         "full_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "boost": 1,
            "fields": {
              "autocomplete": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
              },
              "standard":{
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          },
```

Comment: I add all the same ass my example on mappings but your `brand.keyword` Helps me. Thank you Bro. very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your string as not_analyzed string, for that run the below query

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to replace the `your_type` and `your_index` with your type and index values.

Comment: Thanx bro the brand is String but the categories are array you thing this is problem for the categories = ["categ1", "categ2","categ3"]

Comment: to aggrecate i need to have `"fielddata": True` , You think this is the problem ??

Comment: i steel gate the same result  ``` "brand_aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "10",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "brand",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        },```

Comment: @Georgehatouts check my answer up